# ffmpeg falls every 15 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a problem with ffmpeg on virtual machine!

here is my command

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://1.2.3.4/some_channel.sdp -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 60 ./%s.wav
```

i have ffmpeg version 3.4.6

everything work alright on simple PC. No stops. It works great!

but on VM it falls every 15 seconds  and the last message in the Terminal is

> size=N/A time=00:0014:97 bitrate=N/A speed =   1x
>       video:0kB audio:468kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

```
size=N/A time=00:00:14.54 bitrate=N/A speed= 1x
[mp2 @ 0x5597df2fb940] overread, skip -7 enddists: -6 -6
[mp2 @ 0x5597df2fb940] overread, skip -6 enddists: -4 -4
Last message repeated 1 times
[mp2 @ 0x5597df2fb940] overread, skip -5 enddists: -2 -2
size=N/A time=00:00:15.01 bitrate=N/A speed= 1x
size=N/A time=00:00:15.01 bitrate=N/A speed= 1x
video:0kB audio:469kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Show the complete log from the failing command.

Comment: @llogan i added log as you say

Comment: Unfortunately that is not very helpful. I'm looking for the *complete log* (although you can trim the repeating `overread, skip` lines). The log is text so it is best to copy and paste it. Images of text are less helpful.

Comment: @llogan a added last several lines 
all lines in log file are the same

Comment: That's not the full, complete log. Can't help without it. If you're having trouble getting it you can append `2> ffmpeg.log` to the end of your command.